# ORDER BY with relative data for a specific keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT 
    Users.user_id, Users.location, Profession.name
FROM 
    Users
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    User_Education ON Users.user_id = User_Education.user_id
INNER JOIN 
    Profession ON Profession.profession_id = Users.desired_job
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Exp_Duration ON Exp_Duration.user_id = Users.user_id
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    User_Skill ON Users.user_id = User_Skill.user_id
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
    AND Users.user_id IN (1491, 1493, 1497, 1498)           
    AND Users.active = 1
```

I'm trying to order the results I get returned from this query to match against with a keyword. For an example, I want to be able to pass in 'software engineer' and see the users who are with an active record in the Profession table to get appeared on top. What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Here is one of the many unsuccessful method I used:

```
SELECT 
    Users.user_id, Users.location, Profession.name
FROM 
    Users
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    User_Education ON Users.user_id = User_Education.user_id
INNER JOIN 
    Profession ON Profession.profession_id = Users.desired_job
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Exp_Duration ON Exp_Duration.user_id = Users.user_id
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    User_Skill ON Users.user_id = User_Skill.user_id
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
    AND Users.user_id IN (1491, 1493, 1497, 1498, 1503)           
    AND Users.active = 1 
ORDER BY 
    CASE
       WHEN Profession.name LIKE 'Software Engineer' 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE 1
    END, Profession.name ASC
```

Comment: Can you show us some data?  Are you sure that `Software Engineer` would even match something exactly?

Comment: sure! it definitely has the data. please find the directly copied data from the resultset. 

Software Engineer
Software Engineer
Junior Software Engineer
Software Engineer
Software Engineer

Comment: If you add `Profession.name LIKE 'Software Engineer'` to the `WHERE` clause do you get back any results?

Comment: yup. then i'm only getting software engineers. but i just want them in the top with the other data

Comment: Are you missing some wild cards?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
Profession.name LIKE 'Software Engineer'
```

With

```
Profession.name LIKE ('%' + 'Software Engineer' + '%')
```

And test it.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `full join` and `inner join` just doesn't look right.  In fact, I almost never use `full join`.  In fact, most of the tables in the query are not used in the query.

You seem to want to keep all users, so I suspect this is the query that you want:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.location, p.name
FROM Users u LEFT JOIN
     Profession p
     ON p.profession_id = u.desired_job
WHERE u.user_id IN (1491, 1493, 1497, 1498) AND         
      u.active = 1 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN p.name LIKE '%Software Engineer%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         u.user_id;
```

If you do need the other tables (say for columns references removed from this query), then use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
DECLARE @keyword NVARCHAR(256) = N'Software Engineer'; 
***
ORDER BY  
     IIF([Profession].[name] LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%', NULL, '') ASC
    ,[Profession].[name] ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

No purpose to a `like` if you are not using any wild cards.

You have something else going on as this works fine for me.

```
declare @t table (p varchar(40));
insert @t values 
('cook'),
('cook'),
('cook'),
('engineer'),
('engineer'),
('engineer'),
('engineer'),
('cook'),
('mechanic'),
('mechanic');
select * 
from @t 
order by case when p = 'engineer' 
                   then 0
                   else 1
         end, 
         p;

engineer
engineer
engineer
engineer
cook
cook
cook
cook
mechanic
mechanic
```